# Showing that a harmonic function is constant

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be harmonic function and suppose that exist $C>0$ such that $|u(x)| \leq C(1+\sqrt{\|x\|})$. I want show that $u$ is constant.

My first idea: Show that $C(1+\sqrt{\|x\|})$ is harmonic and use the property of volumetric mean, but $C(1+\sqrt{\|x\|})$ is not harmonic.

I also can not limit for $C(1+\sqrt{\|x\|})$.

I have no more ideas.

Comment: Do you know Harnack Inequality?

Comment: I know, but the excercise is before Harnack Inequality.  but you can use it if you can not it without

Comment: What about if you use the mean value property on large circles for $n=2$ which have the lowest growth in length/area, since it still grows faster than the estimate, so you should easily get the result - in general they are spheres and the growth of their areas is even faster with $n$ higher of course

Comment: Do you know the proof that a bounded harmonic function on $\mathbb R^n$ is constant?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I do

Comment: Won't that proof work for this case as well?

Comment: @Conrad I'm not sure what you have in mind there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For harmonic functions, the following is valid:

$$|D_iu(y)| \leq \frac n R \sup_{\partial B_R(y)} |u|.$$

(Look [Estimates of derivatives of harmonic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714214/estimates-of-derivatives-of-harmonic-function?rq=1) for a simple proof.)

Thus, we have for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a fixed $R$:

$$|D_iu(y)|\leq\frac{nC}{R}(1+\sqrt{R})=\frac{nC}{R}+\frac{nC}{\sqrt{R}}.$$

The RHS of the previous inequality goes to zero when $R\to\infty$. Thus, $D_iu(y)\equiv0,\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $1\leq i\leq n$. Therefore, 
$$Du\equiv0\Rightarrow u=constant.$$

Comment: $\frac{nC}{R} \text{sup }_{\partial B_R(y)}(1+\sqrt{|x|}) \leq \frac{nC}{R}(1+\sqrt{R+|y|})$ right?